# Can i include a popup using the addLabelOnlyMarkers control in Leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet

As title says, i would like to add an onclick popup to the label information on my leaflet map, but using the addLabelOnlyMarkers control.

Answer (score 0):

Label is not a popup. Add a popup like this:

```r
library(leaflet)

x <- tibble::tibble(lat = 40.748817, lon = -73.985428, label = "Empire State Building")

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB") %>% 
  addPopups(lng = x$lon, lat = x$lat, popup = x$label)
```

The thing is it does not make much sense adding the popups without markers, once closed, you cannot open them again. If you supplied sample code and data, we could at least try to guess what is your goal doing this...

[image]